# Distinguish if JAVA is disabled or not installed using Javascript

Tags: javascript, java

How can I distinguish between the following scenarios using a Javascript test in browser?

1. Java is installed but disabled
2. Java is not installed at all

I have checked `deployJava.js` and `navigator.javaEnabled()` but they seem to return `false` in both scenarios if I disable JAVA using JAVA control panel in Windows.

`deployJava.versionCheck("1.5+") //false`

`navigator.javaEnabled()  //false`

Thanks for your help.

P.S. I checked similar answers but they all are related to detecting to some other version of JAVA. I just need to know which of the above mentioned state occurs.

Comment: Question is not about detecting the version of java. I know how to do that. My question is how do i tell if java is disabled by user or its not installed at all.

Comment: My apologies, I judged too fast. Have you checked `getJREs();`?

Comment: @TimS. No prob.Yeah i checked that but it returns `[]` empty object if disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the browser, there's no way to differentiate between the two cases you mention. When you disable java using the control panel, then it doesn't get loaded into the browser, and so the browser cannot tell you if it's installed or not.

You would have a similar issue with other plugins if they had an on-off switch of that form.

Comment: Is it possible using an applet?

Comment: The applet would never be loaded in either case (disabled, not installed) so you still could not tell